# Maximum Frequency Stack Question on LeetCode

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve the maximum frequency stack question on leetcode using a combination of a treeset and a hashMap. My problem is that even with the comparable interface for my custom class, the contains function for treeset does not seem to work properly. It adds multiple items of the same value.

Where am i going wrong?

Here's the code:

```
class FreqStack {
    private int size = 0;
    HashMap<Integer, Element> map;
    TreeSet<Element> set;

    public FreqStack() {
        map = new HashMap<Integer, Element>();
        set = new TreeSet<Element>();
    }

    public void push(int x) {
        size++;
        Element elem = map.get(x);
        if (elem == null) {
            // System.out.println("creating new: " + x);
            elem = new Element(x);
        }
        elem.add(size);
        map.put(x, elem);
        if (set.contains(elem)) {
            System.out.println("set contains: " + elem.val);
            set.remove(elem);
        }
        set.add(elem);

        System.out.println(set.stream().map(v -> v.val).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    public int pop() {
        // size--;
        Element elem = set.pollFirst();
        System.out.println(elem.val);
        elem.remove();

        if (elem.getFreq() > 0) {
            set.add(elem);
        } else {
            map.remove(elem.val);
        }

        System.out.println(set.stream().map(v -> v.val).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return elem.val;
    }

    class Element implements Comparable<Element> {
        int val;
        LinkedList<Integer> rank;

        Element(int val) {
            this.val = val;
            this.rank = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        }

        void add(int count) {
            System.out.println("Adding " + val + " - count: " + count);
            rank.add(count);
        }

        void remove() {
            System.out.println("Removing: " + rank.size());
            rank.pollLast();
        }

        int getRank() {
            return rank.peekLast();
        }

        int getFreq() {
            return rank.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Element e) {
            System.out.println("Comparing: " + val + " and " + e.val);
            if (val == e.val)
                return 0;

            if (getFreq() == e.getFreq()) {
                return e.getRank() - getRank();
            }

            return e.getFreq() - getFreq();
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return val;    
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
           return (o instanceof Element) && (this.compareTo((Element) o) == 0);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Your FreqStack object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * FreqStack obj = new FreqStack();
 * obj.push(x);
 * int param_2 = obj.pop();
 */
```

Here's the part output. Note how it adds 5 twice:

```
Adding 5 - count: 1
Comparing: 5 and 5
[5]
Adding 1 - count: 2
Comparing: 1 and 5
Comparing: 1 and 5
[1, 5]
Adding 2 - count: 3
Comparing: 2 and 5
Comparing: 2 and 1
Comparing: 2 and 5
Comparing: 2 and 1
[2, 1, 5]
Adding 5 - count: 4
Comparing: 5 and 1
Comparing: 5 and 2
Comparing: 5 and 1
Comparing: 5 and 2
[5, 2, 1, 5]
```

Comment: The state used in `compareTo` appears mutable. You have to be careful when that's the case because the `TreeSet` won't reevaluate when the state changes. Meaning you can add two distinct elements, manipulate the state to make the elements equal, and end up with a set that has duplicate elements.

Comment: True. That is why whenever I change the element I poll it - which removes the element. And then add it back. Technically, that should work right?

Answer (score 0):

The compareTo method should only compare element's val, isn't it? Two ways you can solve this are:

- Use HashSet in place of TreeSet.
- Change your compareTO as below:

  ```
  public int compareTo(Element e) {
      System.out.println("Comparing: " + val + " and " + e.val);
      return Integer.compare(val, e.val);
  }
  ```

In case these do not suffice could you please explain a little more what are you trying to achieve when you override compareTo method. It seems you should consider only values of elements, but you are also using Freq and Rank.

Comment: Here's the question I'm trying to solve: https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-frequency-stack/description/

Comment: It's not just the values im trying to compare but also the frequency of an element in the stack and the "rank" which in my case measures when the element was added to the stack. This acts as a tie breaker when the frequency is the same

Comment: Your code seems to be fine to me. Following the leetcode link shared above and changing the remove method as below, just to see if pop is working as expected or not: void remove() {
            System.out.println("Removing: " + val + " which was inserted at index " + (rank.peekLast()));
            rank.pollLast();
        }       It looks fine to me.